# Polynomial identities have equal coefficients

Tags: polynomials

When I was about 17 our teacher showed us how polynomial identities had equal coefficients.

I remember him showing that this was so by moving one polynomial "over to the other side" and showing that if indeed the two sets of coefficients were equal, it was sufficient for the identity to be true.

I can't remember how - or if - he proved it to be necessary i.e. there wasn't another set of non-equal coefficients knocking about that the identity would hold for.

Anyone got any idea how to do it?

Comment: Are you familiar with algebraic structures such as fields, domains and rings? If not, what types of "numbers" are the coefficients of your polynomials, e.g. reals, integers, or integers mod $\,m\,$, or possibly, quaternions?

Comment: At the age of 17, these would normally be integers, sometimes reals - and none of the structures you mention would have been covered.

Comment: The point is that if you know these things *now,* then one can give a more enlightening answer, and a more efficient exposition.

Comment: I agree, Bill. I was just wondering how we did it before we reached those heights!

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(x) = 0$ is an identity, where $f$ is a polynomial, and $f(x)$ denotes the associated polynomial function evaluated at $x$.

Then, every number is a root of the polynomial $f$.

It is well-known that a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ over a field can have at most $n$ roots (e.g. by factoring the polynomial), so $f$ cannot be a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ for any $n$, because it has more than $n$ roots.

Therefore, the only possibility is that $f$ is the zero polynomial.

---

If you're familiar with modular arithmetic, it is interesting to note the above argument fails in a more general setting!!! There are two different ways.

An example of the first way is when doing modular arithmetic modulo $2$, it turns out that the function

$$ x^2 + x \equiv 0 \pmod{2} $$

is an identity, despite the fact the coefficients are nonzero. This polynomial has two roots: $0 \bmod 2$ and $1 \bmod 2$, but it is of degree $2$, so it's okay.

An example of the second way is when doing arithmetic modulo $8$. The functions

$$ 2x^2(x^2 - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$
$$ x^3(x^2 - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$

are two more identities, despite being only degree $4$ and $5$. This is why it's important that the coefficients come from a field (e.g. modular arithmetic with a prime modulus), rather than a more general ring. These examples actually demonstrate three different things that can go wrong in general rings.

Comment: The modular info was new to me and interesting. Thanks.

The ideas expressed in your para starting "It is well-known that a nonzero polynomial..." seem to be from the Fundamental Theorem, which we hadn't covered. He may have cited it unproved, of course, but I was wondering if there were another way.

Comment: @Applied: There are a number of different tricks for proving the theorem, and a few other ones for proving your particular question over fields like the reals and complexes. For example, if the polynomial is of degree $n$ and its largest coefficient has magnitude $c$, then by using them, you can explicitly construct a value $a$ large enough that, when computing $f(a)$, the leading term has magnitude greater than the sum of all of the remaining terms put together, and thus $f(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: That's nice. I've done it for a couple of examples and am wondering how to get a general method. Anyway, it's late now; manyana. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, once I was awake it was obvious (!:-) - I can't remember my teacher doing it that way: perhaps he just said we'd get a polynomial of degree n, so n roots, and hand-waved it away... Thanks for your helpful replies, all of you.